# how to launch shell script from finder

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, launching

I have some shell (Bash) scripts that process some video files in a directory.
Instead of everytime launching a (Open)Terminal window, then typing the script name, I'd prefer to install an icon in the Finder's explorer toolbar so that a simple click on it does the job (like [OpenTerminal](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/01/25/open-terminal-access-mac-terminal-from-finder) does, if you know that tool). The result I imagine is this one :

- click on the icon
- a terminal window appears which automatically does a kind of

  ```
  cd /the/path/where/I/was/in/the/finder/window; run_my_script.sh
  ```

Any idea how to do that ? (it's feasible since OpenTerminal does it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save something like this as an application in AppleScript Editor:

```
activate application "SystemUIServer" -- http://www.openradar.me/9406282
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as text)
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script
    repeat while contents of window 1 starts with linefeed
        delay 0.01 -- wait to get a prompt
    end repeat
    do script "cd " & quoted form of p in window 1
    do script "uptime" in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: ok but how to trigger it with an icon in the finder's explorer toolbar ?

Comment: Just drag it to the toolbar like other toolbar applications.

Answer (score 0):

Add to top of the script,

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd /the/path/where/I/was/in/the/finder/window  
  ....
  ....
```

After that run following command on the terminal

`ln -s run_my_script.sh /bin/run_my_script.sh`

Comment: no, this is exactly what I'd like to avoid. Besides, I don't want to hardcode the current path into the script. I want the script execute in the current folder (the one displayed by the finder), like OpenTerminal does